# How to Send a Copy of Order Confirmation Emails to Dynamic EmailId in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have a made custom module of the **sales rep**. They can create an order for a customer. When sales rep place order at that time order confirmation email copy sent to assign sales reps in order.

I have store sales rep email id in Quote & order both tables. If any query please let me know. Please any can help me

Note: The code is working on the local server. **But In an enterprise, it's not working.**

1. create an event for a set variable. create event.xml

   ```
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="set_email_po_order" instance="Vendor\Modulename\Observer\EmailOrderSetTemplateVarsBefore" />
    </event>
   ```
2. set variable dynamic from the get order table

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Modulename\Observer;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class EmailOrderSetTemplateVarsBefore implements ObserverInterface {

    private $orderEmail;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Modulename\Model\OrderEmail $orderEmail,
        \Vendor\Modulename\Model\SalesrepFactory $salesrepData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
        $this->orderEmail = $orderEmail;
        $this->_salesrepData = $salesrepData;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transportObject = $observer->getData('transportObject');
        if($transportObject->getData('order')){
            try {
                if($order->getSalesrepId()){
                    $getSalesrepData = $this->_salesrepData->create()->load($order->getSalesrepId());          
                    if($getSalesrepData->getEmail()){
                        $notiEmails = $getSalesrepData->getEmail();
                        $this->orderEmail->setSalesrepEmails($notiEmails);
                        $logger->debug("Order email copy send to salesrep sucessfully....");
                    }
                }

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $logger->error('Error while send design customer Email', ['exception' => $e]);
                echo $e->getMessage(); 
            } 
        }
    }
   ```

   }
   ?>
3. create a model for set private

   ```
    <?php
    namespace \Vendor\Modulename\Model;
    class OrderEmail {
    private $extraOrderEmailId;

    public function setSalesrepEmails($email){
        $this->extraOrderEmailId = $email;
    }
    public function getSalesrepEmails()
    {
        return $this->extraOrderEmailId;
    }
   ```

   }
4. Add plugin di.xml

   ```
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
            <plugin name="add_email_to_order_copy" type="Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
   ```
5. Create a plugin file

   ```
    <?php   
     namespace Vendor\Modulename\Plugin\Order\Email\Container;    
     class OrderIdentity{
         public function __construct(
            \Vendor\Modulename\Model\OrderEmail $orderEmail
         ){
             $this->orderEmail = $orderEmail;
         }
          public function afterGetEmailCopyTo(
          \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject,
          $result
          ){
    $additionalEmailId =  $this->orderEmail->getSalesrepEmails();
    if(($additionalEmailId === null) || (!$additionalEmailId) || empty($additionalEmailId)){
        return $result;
    }
    else{
        $additionalEmailId =  explode(",",$this->orderEmail->getSalesrepEmails());
        if(count($additionalEmailId)==0 || empty($additionalEmailId)){
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            if (!empty($result) && is_array($result)){
                foreach($additionalEmailId as $additionalEmail):
                    $result[] = (string) $additionalEmail;
                endforeach;
                return $result;
            }else{
                return $additionalEmailId;
            }
        }
    }
    }
     }
   ```